# Writing helper functions that will probably not be used again

Tags: function, helper

Is this considered questionable programming practice?  For example, you have an (otherwise) very long function, say

```
void setUpRoom(parameters) {
    setUpSofas(parameters);
    setUpTables(parameters);
    hangPictures(parameters);
    // etc...
}
```

If setUpRoom() is only being used once, then so will all the helper functions in them, and hence the helper functions do not faciliate anything elsewhere.  But setUpRoom() would be very long otherwise.  Making the helper functions from the existing long code within setUpRoom also requires some care because parameters need to be passed around among them (e.g. where you put the tables depends on where you already put the sofas, and the pictures may want to be near the tables for some reason, etc...).

Comment: No, conversely. Procedural decomposition is good.

Comment: This approach would allow you to rearrange the setup order of the room without (much) risk if, for example, the requirements changed and hanging the pictures had to happen before the sofas were positioned.